# Counting the occurrences of chararacters in a string

Tags: haskell

I got the task to count the number of occurrences of each (lower case) character in a string. I am not allowed to use any function of the library, I came up with the following, working solution.

```
occur :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
occur y =  [ (x,count x y) | x<-['a'..'z'],  count x y > 0]
```

I was trying at first:

```
occur2 :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
occur2 y =  [ (x,z) | x<-['a'..'z'], z<- count x y,  count x y > 0]
```

I defined the helper function count like this:

```
count :: Char -> String -> Int
count k str = length [n | n <- str, n == k]
```

Two questions:

1. Why is occur2 not working?
2. Is there any way to define occur without my aux function count?

Comment: What the teacher possibly wanted may be a classical helper function with an accumulator parameter. Moving mutable state into parameters is a typical FP trick. Filtering out the character while you're counting, and passing the filtered list to the next counting invocation helps both performance and logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`occur2` isn't working because `count x y` is not a list, so it can't be used for a generator expression like in `z <- count x y`. Instead, use a `let` expression.

You can remove the `count` definition by inlining it.

```
occur :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
occur y = [ (x,z) | x <- ['a'..'z'], let z = length [n | n <- y, n == x], z > 0]
```

If you were to use libraries, a simple and efficient implementation would be to use a [`MultiSet`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-MultiSet.html#t:MultiSet).

```
import qualified Data.MultiSet as MS

occur :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
occur = MS.toAscOccurList . MS.fromList . filter (\c -> c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How is the let expression changing this "length [n | n <- y, n == x]" into a list? Isnt it a form of binder?

Comment: It doesn't change it to a list. `let` is for binding a value like you say.